# How to get a following message.content in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord

```
if "You can move forward." in message.content:
    time.sleep(3)
    await message.channel.send("!step")
    time.sleep(3)
    if "Quest" in message.content:
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("!solve 12")
        time.sleep(5)
    await message.channel.send("!turn right")
    time.sleep(3)
    await message.channel.send("!wall"))
```

Is there a command that will move to the next message.content? I need to add it to the if statement of "Quest". Because after every step there can be quest that needs to be solved and if you enter a different command you would lose.

Everytime I try it the code goes like this:

```
>                                                 "You can move forward"
>                                                 "!step"
>                                                 "Quest" (doesnt get registered)
>                                                 "!turn right"
>                                                 "You Lose!"
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I do not condone self-botting on Discord as it is against its T&C.

Nevertheless, what I think you want to use is [bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Your new code will look like this:

```
if "You can move forward." in message.content:
    time.sleep(3)
    await message.channel.send("!step")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == 'Quest' and m.channel == message.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if msg:
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("!solve 12")
        time.sleep(5)

    await message.channel.send("!turn right")
    time.sleep(3)
    await message.channel.send("!wall"))
```

Comment: I get error - loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook

Comment: Hey @timikk8, can you paste your code in https://mystb.in and send the link here? Also add while line is the error showing up in.